# How to use wireshark to capture python socket packets

Tags: python, sockets, wireshark

I am making a program in python using the socket library and I would like to capture the packets being sent.
my code is

```
from socket import socket, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM


ME = MYIP

sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind((ME, 4444))
sock.listen(0)

otherSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
otherSocket.connect((ME, 4444))

client, addr = sock.accept()

otherSocket.send(b"hello")

print(client.recv(1024))


client.sendall(b"bye")

print(otherSocket.recv(1024))

sock.close()
otherSocket.close()
client.close()
```

When i run it it does what is expected and prints out "hello" and then "bye".
is there any way for me to see these packets being sent using Wireshark??

Comment: Have you tried just using Wireshark and sniffing on the loopback interface?  *"... prints out "hello" and then "bye" ..."* - this is exactly what I would expect based on the code and what also happens in my test. No idea what your expectations are.

Comment: https://www.studytonight.com/network-programming-in-python/using-wireshark#

Comment: https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback